# JPA discriminator undesired

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, javabeans

I know there are several questions on this argument, but I think mine is a bit different.

I'm trying to use JPA notation instead of XML mapping. In my queries always there's an undesired dtype column, and I don't want to use neither discriminator column and formula.

I have four classes as follow:

The first named `ObjectUUID`. All classes extend this super class.

This class is used only to define id field, as follow:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ObjectUUID {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    protected String id;

    // getter and setter and other static methods
}
```

Then I have another class, named `TrackSys` where I define other fields (as insert date and update date) as follow:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class TrackSys extends ObjectUUID{

    @Column(name="dt_ins") 
    private CustomCalendar dtInsert;
    @Column(name="dt_upd")
    private CustomCalendar dtUpdate;

    // getter and setter
}
```

the third and the forth classes are beans mapped on DB, as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
public class PatientUUID extends TrackSys {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
public class Patient extends PatientUUID {

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name="name") 
    private String name;
    @Column(name="cf")
    private String cf;

    // getter and setter
}
```

I define a repository to query my patient table, as follow:

```
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Long> {
    List<Patient> findBySurname(String surname);
}
```

When my Patient query runs, the generated SQL is the follow:

```
select patient0_.id as id2_2_, patient0_.dt_ins as dt_ins3_2_,
patient0_.dt_upd as dt_upd4_2_, patient0_.cf as cf7_2_,
patient0_.surname as surname8_2_, patient0_.name as name11_2_,
from patient patient0_ where patient0_.dtype='Patient'
and patient0_.surname=?
```

Now...

I don't want dtype column and I don't want to use discriminator formula.

With the XML mapping this is possible without particular properties to specify.

With JPA annotation I try in order:

Use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` but dtype is always present

Use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` but dtype is always present

Now, my feeling versus dtype is only hate, how can I get this simple query, as follow:

```
select patient0_.id as id2_2_, patient0_.dt_ins as dt_ins3_2_,
patient0_.dt_upd as dt_upd4_2_, patient0_.cf as cf7_2_,
patient0_.surname as surname8_2_, patient0_.name as name11_2_,
from patient patient0_ where patient0_.surname=?
```

Comment: "With the XML mapping this is possible without particular properties to specify." You manage to use the same table for both classes and no dtype column is needed ??? It seems surprising.

Comment: JPA provider specific. SINGLE_TABLE implies you MUST have a discriminator. JOINED does not imply the requirement to have one, however some don't force such things on you, and others do

Comment: @davidxxx: Yes, two classes PatientUUID e Patient are mapped on the same table, patient. The first has polymorphism="explicit", so the query pick up good.

Comment: @BillyFrost: I try to JOINED but nothing. May be I'm wrong in some definitions on JOINED strategy

Comment: As already said ... some JPA providers don't allow you to NOT have discriminator with JOINED (you chose Hibernate, so accept what it restricts you to have). Depends where you put the Inheritance annotation also ... can only specify in the root class